# Shorten a big string without cutting words and save into array in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have different lengths of string. These are very large strings, between 4000 to 20 000 characters.
I wish to cut a string all 4000 characters without cutting a full middle of a word. Then store the cut string in an array

I can cut my string and recover each cut end. However, I need a loop because some strings are bigger than others

My code currently :

```
let string = 'One string with 9771 character, including "."';

let array = [];
let string2 = '';

var cutat = string.lastIndexOf('.',4000);
if(cutat!=-1){
  string2=string.substring(0,cutat)+".";
}

string = string.split(string2)
string = string[1]

array[0] = string2;

var cutat = string.lastIndexOf('.',4000);
if(cutat!=-1){
  string2=string.substring(0,cutat)+".";
}

string = string.split(string2)
string = string[1]

array[1] = string2;

var cutat = string.lastIndexOf('.',4000);
if(cutat!=-1){
  string2=string.substring(0,cutat)+".";
}

array[2] = string2;

console.log(array)
```

Currently, I get my array with my string divided every 4000 characters without cutting a word in the middle.

```
Array = ['the first 4000 characters.','the second.','the last.']
```

Now, I would like to make a loop to achieve this, because I have smaller strings and larger strings, so it will probably cut more or fewer times this string. How to do? Thank you

Comment: Are you looking to split between sentences or words? Your text says one but the code says something else

Comment: Split between sentences like that : `let string = "abc def. ghij kl."; array = ['abc def.', 'ghij kl.'];` @MTCoster

Comment: `split('.')`? `"abc def. ghij kl.".split('.').filter(s => !!s).map(s => \`${s}.\`)`

Comment: @MoshFeu That's what I want, but I want the split to be done every 4000 characters on the "." the closest and not to each "."

Comment: Got you. So seems you got an answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using `.substr` method and while loop:

```
const s_limit = 4000;
function cutter(str) {
    var chunks = [];
    while(str.lastIndexOf('.', s_limit) > 0) {
        var ind = str.lastIndexOf('.', s_limit)+1;
        chunks.push(str.substr(0, ind));
        str = str.substr(ind);
    }
    return chunks;
}
```